# javascript video player not seeking correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a `JavaScript` application which utilizes [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/docs/setup/) as the video player. One of the features is to be able to bookmark the video, so there are some links in the page like:

```
<p><a href="" onclick="seek('00:03:00');">00:03:00</a></p>
<p><a href="" onclick="seek('00:10:45');">00:10:45</a></p>
<p><a href="" onclick="seek('00:25:30');">00:25:30</a></p>
<p><a href="" onclick="seek('00:45:31');">00:45:31</a></p>
<p><a href="" onclick="seek('01:01:01');">01:01:01</a></p>
<p><a href="" onclick="seek('01:11:11');">01:11:11</a></p>
```

Which will trigger the following functions:

```
         function convertToSeconds(time){
                var timeInSeconds = 0;
                var slice =  time.split(":");
                // make sure it is in the format 00:00:00
                if(slice.length == 3){
                    var hours        = parseInt(slice[0]);
                    var minutes      = parseInt(slice[1]);
                    var seconds      = parseInt(slice[2]);

                    timeInSeconds = seconds + minutes*60 + hours*3600;  
                }
                return timeInSeconds;
            }

            function seek(time){
                var myPlayer = _V_("example_video_1");
                var seconds = convertToSeconds(time);
                var whereAt = myPlayer.duration();
                console.log(seconds);
                if(seconds <= whereAt){
                    myPlayer.currentTime(seconds);
                    myPlayer.play();
                }

                return;
            }
```

`ConvertToSeconds` converts a string in the format `'00:03:00'` into `180` seconds.
Then I apply that to seek to that position in the video. Although it seeks correctly the position in the video, the player cursor returns to the begin of the video, instead of staying where is supposed to be. Any ideas why is that happening?